# How do I see edits to my question?

Tags: support, editing

My question shows it has been edited, but I see no way to view the edits.

How can I see exactly what was edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the question, click on the link next to "edited" to the left of your avatar.

Comment: To clarify, the link is the time to the right of the word "edited".

Answer (score 0):

Found it, apparently not available from the question directly (perhaps it should be?), but if you go to your recent activity (click letter icon to left of your name at top of window) and pick the revisions tab.

Comment: It is available from the question directly, see my answer.

Comment: Or from the question, click on the time of edit.